# generate subpages from template in jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Is it possible to have a template in Jekyll, that will be filled for each subpage of a certain category with different data..

Say I have `portfolio` page, then I link to my works from there, each separate `work` page is using the same template, just the text and pics are changing.

So what I would like to have is `portfolio/work1`, `portfolio/work2` generated from the same template and then I would iterate over `_data yml files` to fill in details for each work...

Is that possible in Jekyll? I couldn't find any articles on that topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [default setup](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) for your portofolio folder.

1. In **_config.yml**, set :

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "portofolio"
      type: "pages"
    values:
      layout: "work"
```

2. Create a **_layouts/work.html** template.

_

3. In your **portofolio/indexhtml** page

If you want to override layout, just do :

```
---
layout: page
...
---
```

Comment: I have another page that contains some html, js, css and this page contain a cv. I want to use this, not markdown. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with 'Collections' which is a function in Jekyll. See [Jekyll Collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/). If you are not sure what Collections is for then maybe Ben Balter's [explanation](http://ben.balter.com/2015/02/20/jekyll-collections/) could help.

In your situation: You want a `portfolio` page with subpages for each piece of work. Create a collection named `Portfolio` in your `_config.yml` like below:

```
# Collections
collections:
  portfolio:
    output: true
```

Then create a folder called `_portfolio` in your jekyll files. You then can clarify in your front matter on each piece of work i.e. `work1.md` inside `_portfolio` which could display images, tags etc along with content like you would write a post in Jekyll. In your front-matter for each work example, you can define what template/layout you would want to use for the work examples.

Comment: maybe I didn't explain myself best, this way I would still have to define page for each work piece, and repeat myself copying layout and updating text and pics sources in each of them.. I was hoping for one time layout definition with simple structure, and then in each block have iteration over different data..

Comment: Fortunately I found just what I needed.. [avillafiorita/jekyll-datapage_gen · GitHub] is good,have a look at it! https://github.com/avillafiorita/jekyll-datapage_gen

Comment: Good to see that you have found a solution to what you were looking for. I had thought Collections would be it.